# Why can't I find LNNVL in DBA_PROCEDURES

Tags: oracle

LNNVL exists, because the following statement works.

```
 select 1 from dual where not(LNNVL(1=1));
```

But I can't find it in DBA_PROCEDURE

```
SELECT *
  FROM SYS.DBA_PROCEDURES
 WHERE UPPER (procedure_name) = 'LNNVL';
```

> NULL

It's a built-in  procedure but REGXXP_LIKE too and the following query return a line

```
 SELECT *
  FROM SYS.DBA_PROCEDURES
 WHERE UPPER (procedure_name) = 'REGEXP_LIKE';
```

Comment: `NOT` is not a function, you do not need brackets around the expression it is negating. `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE NOT LNNVL(1=1)`

Comment: OK. but LNNVL is a function. I've used not(lnvl) only to have a query that returns something. But the first queries proves that LNNVL is function that exists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `regexp_like` in the `dba_procedures` view is the version in the `STANDARD` package.

Essentially that means that it's available in PL/SQL; so you can do:

```
bool_var := regexp_like(...);
```

But you can't do:

```
bool_var := lnnvl(...);
```

That dictionary view is nothing to do with [the built-in functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Functions.html#GUID-D079EFD3-C683-441F-977E-2C9503089982) available from SQL, only those available in PL/SQL. [Not all built-in functions are available in PL/SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-828EB30D-32B4-49E3-90D5-9302172D6EC2), so they aren't all replicated in the `STANDARD` package - you can use that same dictionary view or `describe standard` to see what is defined in that package.